# Why was the new controversial TOS change not highlighted on the per site metas?

Tags: discussion, meta, terms-of-service

I don't normally check the main meta at https://meta.stackexchange.com/, but I do check the SO meta here every single day.

Imagine my surprise when I accidentally found out that there was a massively controversial terms of service change 16 days ago that I didn't even know about.  And I thought I'd been keeping on top of things.

Shouldn't this have also been highlighted in the per site metas?

[A new (2018) update to our Terms of Service is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309746/a-new-2018-update-to-our-terms-of-service-is-here)

Comment: I could've sworn that it was in the featured post box for a few days... perhaps that was a different post

Comment: Whaaaaat? Controversial terms of service? /Goes to check out why/ (Obviously I didn't know this until now.)

Comment: The MSE post mentions (or maybe it is just a comment by Tim Post somewhere...) they will be notifying every user by e-mail shortly if they haven't already sent one to you.

Comment: @TylerH looks like [this post by Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310286/2419190): "*I have, as I type this, a draft of our GDPR announcement in my editor, which I plan to publish at some point today or tomorrow. In it, I'll be letting folks know that things take effect on 2018-05-29, and that email notifications will go out near that time.*"

Comment: @DavyM Wow, you have a lot of episodes of the soap opera to catch up. _"This is just a saga now"_

Answer (score 40):

There was a "Featured on Meta" post for several days telling people that there were changes to the TOS. Such posts are, as I understand it, seen across all sites in a yellow box to the right of everyone's screen on every page. And there was a follow-up "Featured on Meta" post about changes to those changes.

You can ignore MSE; that's fine. But posts are only "Featured on Meta" if they're *important*; that's why the feature exists. So you should probably pay attention to them ;)

I can only think of two ways to highlight something *more* than this: top-banners, and sending you e-mail. Maybe the TOS being changed was worth a top banner, but you really shouldn't ignore featured posts in the right.

SO was not trying to hide anything or slip things by anyone.

Comment: Note that the m.se featured posts are not shown in the sidebar on m.so, only on SO proper.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there _was_ a reason. Not sure what it was now.

Comment: That might be why I missed it, I usually mostly only look at meta SO, not SO itself nowdays.

Comment: FWIW, the new ToS has been postponed. It's still not active yet. That's why they haven't sent the announcement personally thru inbox or email.

Comment: _I can only think of two ways to highlight something more than this: top-banners, and sending you e-mail._ Also, the "NEW" icon, unless that's what you call top-banners. But I imagine a top-banner being a full-width banner like for the message "_Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load._".

Comment: Personally - I would be annoyed if I got a banner or an email about it. I realize they had to send one for the GDPR anyway but I still find it kind of annoying to get emails that don't contain content I care about.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well, that's certainly an impossible dream :-) Companies can never be expected to know which of their millions or billions of users will be annoyed at a given email.

Answer (score 10):

There were several network-wide Meta.SE posts. The original highlighted the change, but there was a massive backlash against the arbitration clauses.

- [A new (2018) update to our Terms of Service is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309746/a-new-2018-update-to-our-terms-of-service-is-here)
- [We're examining the implementation of arbitration in the 2018 ToS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309797/were-examining-the-implementation-of-arbitration-in-the-2018-tos-update)
- [Electronic opt-out, correcting miscommunication, and additional questions answered about the 2018 ToS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer)

And just in case you missed it (not controversial, just another policy change)

- [Brace yourselves: The GDPR is coming!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310321/brace-yourselves-the-gdpr-is-coming)

Perhaps they should have made a top banner but people haven't been keen on that in the past either. Either way, they did attempt to notify you.