# Why is there no explanation/hint when a big UI change occurs?

Tags: discussion, user-experience

Today I got the 'June 2018' UI change. I always need to time to adjust, and it would make my life a lot easier if I was greeted with a popup / hint / link somewhere explaining the changes; and ways to change stuff back (if possible).

When Google makes bigger UI changes, it almost always explains the changes or even announce the changes so they don't hit that hard when they arrive.

Why is this not done on Stack Overflow?

Comment: There was a post in MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes

Comment: Yes, but how whould I would I be *notified* before these changes happen? I am not continually reading all parts of my SO screen; and a smallish read-once pop-up would help a lot, or a indicator on my avatar, or something similar

Comment: If you word it "June 2018" based on my previous question title, please be aware that I made up the name: "June 2018" isn't the official name of today's change.

Comment: @Cœur: the real name of the change is _Let's Move Everyone's Cheese For A Laugh_.

Comment: It was announced and discussed many times, but long before it went into production.  They don't keep it a secret when big changes do get released, always look at the yellow box at the upper-right for announcements under the "Featured" heading.

Comment: @HansPassant: I just realize it after reading your comment. I think the `FEATURED ON META` should use contrasting colors instead of gray.

Comment: @HansPassant The fact that announcements of such major changes are given roughly the same visibility as "what can we do about this random problem I don't care about possibly caused by this random user I don't care about do this random thing I don't care about on this post I don't care about"-type posts seems like a problem. If you continuously throw text someone doesn't care about at them, they'll start ignoring it and wouldn't notice if there's something they do care about, and wouldn't think to look there to find it.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a way to go back to the old layout. That new column on the left takes up too much space. There's less space for the actual content. Adblocker doesn't remove the column unfortunately.

Comment: I think the problem came about in that there was a notice in the notification/news box a couple of weeks back, but at the time it came it didnt apply, I didnt have the change, by the time the change came around id forgotten..

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier you can disable the left panel it in your preferences. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/243674

Comment: @BugFinder [Live: Left nav, new theming and responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908) is current featured on (I'm assuming) all non-Meta sites (although I personally would've started the title with "New UI changes" or something, because none of the terms in the current title meant much to me before I read the post).

Comment: @Dukeling I think I read : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes which was posted april, so now its June, sorry Ive read and done a lot since then so I actually had forgotten it was coming...  Yes its live on stackoverflow but I read the post probably in april.. so hence forgoten

Comment: @SurajRao To be fair people shouldn't have to go to site X to read about a change to the UI on site Y. That's poor UX.

Comment: Uh, honestly: what’s there to explain? Navigation is now on the left. Doesn’t seem to require a manual.

Comment: I actually like the UI and agree with Konrad - it doesn't take a rocket genius to know how it works.  Its not windows 3.1 to windows 95 upgrade.  Its move top navs to to left and done.

Comment: Perhaps it's appearing differently on my screen(?) but the left column is a huge waste of space. I would love to go back to the old UI. In the past I would have used stylish or greasemonkey to fix it, but I've never been able to do styling changes properly since firefox quantum.

Comment: @TryHarder You do know you can disable the left nav, yes? See the instructions on the announcement [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310908/271280). It's not completely going back to the old UI but you can reclaim the whitespace.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368197/why-was-the-new-controversial-tos-change-not-highlighted-on-the-per-site-metas

Comment: This was a pretty minor UI change in my opinion. Some buttons (which personally I almost never use) are now in a slightly different spot. If there weren't so many MSO post about it I might not have even noticed.

Comment: @Ajean I already had, but the white space remains.

Answer (score 52):

Although I do not work for SO I can say that they do publicly talk about this stuff **a lot** usually on the "Featured" or "Hot" meta posts you'll find on the yellow/gold div on the right side top of your screen.

[image: Community bulletin mentioning the UI changes]

This particular change was discussed many many times including the team stating this was going out to several beta testers before hitting everyone.

I will say this...the one thing Google and some of the other major sites do that probably Stack Exchange could / should do is...

When a new layout or major update is done Google makes the site's background kind of grayish and sets focus to new elements with an arrow pointing at something new and explaining how it works. You click "next" and it shows you the next feature, etc. You can always click the "I got it" button to tell google, "hey I get what you mean now get out of my way and let me use it" (they do this in the new Gmail client as well).

It is pretty effective because it becomes a sort of tutorial for the end user. It signals to the user that something has changed (by graying out the background).  It highlights the new features by bringing focus (color, arrows, text, etc.) to it. It explains what it does and actually lets you interact with it. It is progressive in that it goes out of its way to show you the next tidbit of new feature(s) within the update. It's dismissible for power users who can pick up new features and understand them right out of the box.

Sample library that uses this type of technique: https://introjs.com/

Comment: I'm curious, whats the name of this "technique"? Been trying to find how to do this but can't even figure out a name to call this so I can search it

Comment: It's just a tutorial, no?

Comment: @André - I've been looking for that terminology for probably the last 6 months - I cannot figure out what to type into google...so if anyone else knows that would be perfect...maybe someone on ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: @zack the problem is searching `tutorial` you only get tutorials of users teaching you how to make a website. (I didn't tried advanced filters to narrow the search down)

Comment: @JonH this looks promising https://introjs.com/ :P searched: `guide users through website`

Comment: @André - I posted this on ux.stackexchange keep an eye out: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/118834/looking-for-word-or-definition-of-intro-of-a-site

Comment: @André - Excellent find I have been looking for this for quite some time!  Will be making use of it!

Comment: @André One word for it is a wizard, e.g. 'new user wizard'

Comment: You shouldn't have to be abreast of meta discussions in order to use the site effectively. These changes certainly merit some direct-to-user hand-holding. Lost opportunity, imo. C'est la vie...

Comment: Why Alex Miller has an hexagon? [edit: oh, it's a stackoverflow-for-teams stuff]

Comment: This screenshot is disturbing at so many levels. It contains: (1) an avatar that doesn't match the answerer, (2) creepy elitist hexagon, (3) soulless machine-generated rectangular selection (4) tasteless stock image of an arrow. Can you please replace it with an appropriate one?

Comment: @André Just my two cents, I have always called this a WalkThrough. Page walkthrough, feature walkthrough etc......

Comment: You got to admit someone in the world wide web needs to come to some sort of conclusion on what this design methodology is called.  There are too many terms for it and it leads to too much searching.  That searching yields mostly results that don't target what you are really after.  I know I am dreaming...but just sayin'.